# How to Convert SSIS Package xml to Azure Data Factory xml Format?

Tags: azure-data-factory, etl, pipeline, ssis-2012

Hi there i have SSIS packages and i want to move jobs to Azure Data Factory pipelines.
I dont mean execute SSIS package. Im looking for a easy way to move packages activities to adf pipeline. All helps are welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct tool to convert the ssis into ADF Pipelines as ADF as a tool is still under development and doesn't have all the features as that of ssis till date.
You would have to understand your current ssis flow and manually design the ADF pipelines based on functionality and insome cases integrate other Azure offerings like Azure function, Azure Batch etc to write some custom logics similar to script task in ssis.